# How to add default homepage to Relying Party when using Windows Identity Foundation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, wif, claims-based-identity

Integrating WIF into regular ASP.NET 4.0 website.

I have STS setup and when I navigate to my RP website, it redirects me to STS Login page.

What I want to do is I have Home.aspx in my RP. It is a public page open to everyone. It has have a Login link. When the I click that link it takes me to the STS login page and upon logout I get redirected to Home.aspx again.

**Issue:**
I have set in RP's web.config to allow access to everyone to Home.aspx and Set up as the startup page. I also have it setup as Default document. But when I navigate to my site, it takes me to STS Login page.

**Why doesn't it take me to home.aspx?**

If I manually modify the url to go to home.aspx, it is allowing me.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/71806907-393f-4782-9c30-971be94a2b62/

But that's really a weird workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The link shows how to unprotect a page i.e. a page that can be accessed without a redirect to ADFS.

You could simply put a link on that page that goes to the ADFS login page.

Comment: I totally understand that and I already have <location path="home.aspx">...<allow users="*"/>...</location>. I can access the page if I manually access the home.aspx by entering the url in the browser. So public access isn't a problem. The problem is WIF won't pickup the default document / starup page unless I allow everyone access to my entire root folder. That actually defies the purpose of location element.